# Clicking "comment" or "stats" on a community ad brings up "framing is not allowed"

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, framing

Clicking on the "comment" or "stats" link on a community ad brings up a dialog like this:

[image: framing not allowed]

On pressing OK, the page is loaded as normal. This is in Chrome 12.

Comment: We need some way to ask about community ads that does *not* set the question as a community ads question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deployment - cause:  being trapped inside of an iframe when displayed from within adzerk.