# Answer being composed automatically (in error)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

I was just reading a question here on meta ([Clicking "comment" or "stats" on a community ad brings up "framing is not allowed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93649/clicking-comment-or-stats-on-a-community-ad-brings-up-framing-is-not-allowed)) and I found an answer already composed for me:
[image: Automated Answer]

Comment: Just to note, it's pre-populated for me, too.

Comment: Why not just use a different tag.  Like [meta-cummunity-ads]?

Answer (score 12):

That text is auto-populated for questions that are tagged [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads). (Currently there are two.)

That is the required format for the [community ad submission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011). The tag is also the [suggested method](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for finding the most recent submission question to add your ad.

Comment: This is correct. So obviously the tag should not be applied to questions *about* community ads, but only those requesting submission of community ad proposals.

Comment: Maybe use [community-ad-submission] for the submission posts (and have that one trigger the auto-populated text)

Comment: Hah, interesting. I wonder what the tag should be then..

Comment: And I thought I had an old draft lingering around.